# Java spring без xml и jsp

Tags: java, веб-программирование, spring

Хочу написать свое web приложение. Структура проекта:

[image: Структура]

Так вот. сейчас все работает если я в адресной строке пишу `http://localhost:8080/pages/home.html`

Никак не могу разобраться что надо добавить чтоб не писать html и pages.

Сейчас решение у меня такое. 
`MvcConfig.java` :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@PropertySources(value = {@PropertySource("classpath:/application.properties")})
@ComponentScan("my.company")
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/pages/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        templateResolver.setOrder(10);
        return templateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        return templateEngine;
    }



    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
                .addResourceHandler("/style/**","/images/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/style/", "/images/");
    }

}
```

и простой контроллер

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class PageController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String homePage(ModelMap model) {
        return "home";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loginPage(ModelMap model) {
        return "login";
    }
}
```

Можно ли как-то обойтись без контроллера? или обязательно писать для каждой html свой контроллер?

Comment: Посмотрите сюда: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-view-controller думаю это то что вам надо

Comment: Да, это работает без контроллера. Но тогда получается если я добавляю страницу `user.html`, то мне надо в мой класс `MvcConfig` добавить 
`registry.addViewController("/user").setViewName("user");`

Comment: Возможно есть смысл создать один контроллер с PathVariable и её значение возвращать как имя вьюхи. Правда всё равно будет один контроллер, но он будет всегда один. И ничего не надо будет дописывать. Но возможно надо будет что-то придумывать если пользователь запросит что-то не стандартное, типа index/bla/bla

Comment: разве `/pages/` это не `context root` web-приложения, который можно поправить в дескрипторе развёртывания?